# Pre-populating the fields in a form from database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am having a user logged in section in my project and i uses session for storing the datas of the particular user. In the logged in section i am having a form named business.php and the table named tbl_business to store the data from the form. But i need to pre-populate some particular fields in the form business.php from another table named tbl_user which contains some common datas such as address, name etc. Both these are in a session.

How can i implement it? i didn't tried nothing, need some suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just echo the contents in the value attribute of the input, e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="a" value="<?php echo $this->myContent; ?>" />
```

Please note that you should escape your output data, to prevent XSS / tag breaks, something like:

```
<input type="text" name="a" value="<?php echo addslashes(htmlentities($this->myContent)); ?>" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the XSS tricks Robin

Answer (score 0):

You can populate form element use value attribute.

ex:- `<input type="text" value="<?php echo $session->name?>" name="name" />`